# Fullcalendar: How to fix position of events

Tags: javascript, html, css, fullcalendar

When creating an event using Ruby on Rails with Fullcalendar.js, they get this strange margin on the top of the slot. On the image below, the event (in red) should start at 11am and finish at 12am, but is not following the grid.

The object sent it's in the correct time and timezone.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
const calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
        plugins: [interactionPlugin, timeGrid, dayGrid, listView],
        initialView: 'timeGridWeek',
        headerToolbar: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek'
        },
        select: info => {
            // Remove the previous click handler if it exists
            if (currentSelectHandler) {
                document.getElementById('confirmBookingBtn').removeEventListener('click', currentSelectHandler);
            }

            currentSelectHandler = () => {
                console.log(info);
                addBooking(info.startStr, info.endStr, bookableGroupId, calendar);
                modalInstance.hide();
            };

            // Attach the new click handler
            document.getElementById('confirmBookingBtn').addEventListener('click', currentSelectHandler);

            // Set the confirmation text and show the modal
            createConfirmationText(info.startStr, info.endStr, pricePerHalfHour);
            modalInstance.show();
        },
        selectAllow: function(selectInfo) {
            // Parse the selection start and end times
            const start = new Date(selectInfo.startStr);
            const end = new Date(selectInfo.endStr);

            // Check if the selection is within business hours
            return isSelectionWithinBusinessHours(start, end, availabilities);
        },
        eventClick: info => {
            if (currentCancelHandler) {
                // Remove the previous click handler if it exists
                document.getElementById('confirmCancelBtn').removeEventListener('click', currentCancelHandler);
            }

            currentCancelHandler = () => {
                cancelBooking(info.event.id);
                info.event.remove();
                cancelModalInstance.hide();
            };

            // Attach the new click handler and show modal
            document.getElementById('confirmCancelBtn').addEventListener('click', currentCancelHandler);
            cancelModalInstance.show();
        },
        nowIndicator: true,
        slotMinTime: '06:00',
        slotMaxTime: '22:00',
        slotDuration: '00:30:00',
        slotLabelFormat: {
            hour: '2-digit',
            minute: '2-digit',
            hour12: false,
        },
        eventTimeFormat: {
            hour: '2-digit',
            minute: '2-digit',
            hour12: false,
        },
        allDaySlot: false,
        selectable: true,
        selectOverlap: false,
        businessHours: businessHoursConfig,
        events: [...events]
    });

    calendar.render();
```

Comment: fullcalendar won't do this by default. From your screenshot, it looks like you have have some custom CSS on the page. This is probably interfering somehow with the fullcalendar layout. So I would start by debugging that using your browser's developer tools.